# Simplexml_load_string() fail to parse error

Tags: php, simplexml, google-weather-api

I'm trying to load parse a Google Weather API response (Chinese response).

[Here](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=11791&hl=zh-CN) is the API call.

```
// This code fails with the following error
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=11791&hl=zh-CN');
```

> ( ! ) Warning: simplexml_load_string()
>   [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 1: parser error : Input
>   is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding
>   ! Bytes: 0xB6 0xE0 0xD4 0xC6 in
>   C:\htdocs\weather.php on line 11

Why does loading this response fail?

How do I encode/decode the response so that `simplexml` loads it properly?

**Edit:** Here is the code and output.

```
<?php
$googleData = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=11102&hl=zh-CN');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($googleData);
```

> ( ! ) Warning: simplexml_load_string()
>   [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 1: parser error : Input
>   is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding
>   ! Bytes: 0xB6 0xE0 0xD4 0xC6 in
>   C:\htdocs\test4.php on line 3 Call
>   Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0020  314264  {main}(
>   ) ..\test4.php:0
>   2 0.1535  317520  simplexml_load_string
>   ( string(1364) )  ..\test4.php:3
>
> ( ! ) Warning: simplexml_load_string()
>   [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   t_system
>   data="SI"/>
>
> ( ! ) Warning: simplexml_load_string()
>   [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in
>   C:\htdocs\test4.php on line 3 Call
>   Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0020  314264  {main}(
>   ) ..\test4.php:0
>   2 0.1535  317520  simplexml_load_string
>   ( string(1364) )  ..\test4.php:3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem here is that SimpleXML doesn't look at the HTTP header to determine the character encoding used in the document and simply assumes it's UTF-8 even though Google's server does advertise it as

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=GB2312
```

You can write a function that will take a look at that header using the super-secret magic variable `$http_response_header` and transform the response accordingly. Something like that:

```
function sxe($url)
{   
    $xml = file_get_contents($url);
    foreach ($http_response_header as $header)
    {   
        if (preg_match('#^Content-Type: text/xml; charset=(.*)#i', $header, $m))
        {   
            switch (strtolower($m[1]))
            {   
                case 'utf-8':
                    // do nothing
                    break;

                case 'iso-8859-1':
                    $xml = utf8_encode($xml);
                    break;

                default:
                    $xml = iconv($m[1], 'utf-8', $xml);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return simplexml_load_string($xml);
}
```

Comment: so do I just copy paste this in my php and change the variables and it will recognise things like `&frasl;` which is a `/`

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** I can reproduce the problem. Also, Firefox is auto-sniffing the character set as "chinese simplified" when I output the raw XML feed. Either the Google feed is serving incorrect data (Chinese Simplified characters instead of UTF-8 ones), or it is serving different data when not fetched in a browser - the content-type header in Firefox clearly says `utf-8`.

Converting the incoming feed from Chinese Simplified (GB18030, this is what Firefox gave me) into UTF-8 works:

```
 $incoming = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=11791&hl=zh-CN');
 $xml = iconv("GB18030", "utf-8", $incoming);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

it doesn't explain nor fix the underlying problem yet, though. I don't have time to take a deep look into this right now, maybe somebody else does. To me, it looks like Google are in fact serving incorrect data (which would surprise me. I didn't know they made mistakes like us mortals. :P)

Comment: Pekka: I've tried that, the xml looks fine, but I get tons of parse errors when I pass it to simplexml_load_string :(. Do I need to cast it to a UTF-8 string or something? Does loading it through php give you an error?

Comment: @John hang on, I'll try it out.

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks! Atleast now I can feel good knowing that it wasn't my code that broke the system xD.

Comment: @John you're welcome. I can be wrong but the way it looks like, this seems to actually be faulty data.

Comment: Actually, the server does advertise using the GB2312 charset for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Just came accross this.
This seems to work (the function itself I found on the web, just updated it a bit).:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 


function getWeather() {

$requestAddress = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=11791&hl=zh-CN";
// Downloads weather data based on location.
$xml_str = file_get_contents($requestAddress,0);
$xml_str = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $xml_str); 

$xml_str = iconv("GB18030", "utf-8", $xml_str);


// Parses XML
$xml = new SimplexmlElement($xml_str, TRUE);
// Loops XML
$count = 0;
echo '<div id="weather">';

foreach($xml->weather as $item) {

    foreach($item->forecast_conditions as $new) {

        echo "<div class=\"weatherIcon\">\n";
         echo "<img src='http://www.google.com/" .$new->icon['data'] . "'   alt='".$new->condition['data']."'/><br>\n";
        echo "<b>".$new->day_of_week['data']."</b><br>";
        echo "Low: ".$new->low['data']." &nbsp;High: ".$new->high['data']."<br>";
        echo "\n</div>\n";
        }

}

echo '</div>';
}


getWeather();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the script I have made in php to parse Google Weather API.

```
 <?php

function sxe($url)
{
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
foreach ($http_response_header as $header)
{
if (preg_match('#^Content-Type: text/xml; charset=(.*)#i', $header, $m))
{
switch (strtolower($m[1]))
{

case 'utf-8':
// do nothing
break;

case 'iso-8859-1':
$xml = utf8_encode($xml);
break;

default:
$xml = iconv($m[1], 'utf-8', $xml);
}
break;
}
}
return simplexml_load_string($xml);
}


$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=46360&h1=en-us');
$information = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information");
$current = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions");
$forecast = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions");


print "<br><br><center><div style=\"border: 1px solid; background-color: #dddddd; background-image: url('http://mc-pdfd-live.dyndns.org/images/clouds.bmp'); width: 450\">";


print "<br><h3>";
print $information[0]->city['data'] . "&nbsp;" . $information[0]->unit_system['data'] . "&nbsp;" .     $information[0]->postal_code['data'];
print "</h3>";
print "<div style=\"border: 1px solid; width: 320px\">";
print "<table cellpadding=\"5px\"><tr><td><h4>";
print "Now";
print "<br><br>";
print "<img src=http://www.google.com" . $current[0]->icon['data'] . ">&nbsp;";
print "</h4></td><td><h4>";
print "<br><br>";
print "&nbsp;" . $current[0]->condition['data'] . "&nbsp;";
print "&nbsp;" . $current[0]->temp_f['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "<br>";
print "&nbsp;" . $current[0]->wind_condition['data'];
print "<br>";
print "&nbsp;" . $current[0]->humidity['data'];
print "<h4></td></tr></table></div>";




print "<table cellpadding=\"5px\"><tr><td>";


print "<table cellpadding=\"5px\"><tr><td><h4>";
print "Today";
print "<br><br>";
print "<img src=http://www.google.com" . $forecast[0]->icon['data'] . ">&nbsp;";
print "</h4></td><td><h4>";
print "<br><br>";
print  $forecast[0]->condition['data'];
print "<br>";
print  "High&nbsp;" . $forecast[0]->high['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "<br>";
print  "Low&nbsp;" . $forecast[0]->low['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "</h4></td></tr></table>";

print "<table cellpadding=\"5px\"><tr><td><h4>";
print  $forecast[2]->day_of_week['data'];
print "<br><br>";
print "<img src=http://www.google.com" . $forecast[2]->icon['data'] . ">&nbsp;";
print "</h4></td><td><h4>";
print "<br><br>";
print  "&nbsp;" . $forecast[2]->condition['data'];
print "<br>";
print  "&nbsp;High&nbsp;" . $forecast[2]->high['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "<br>";
print  "&nbsp;Low&nbsp;" . $forecast[2]->low['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "</h4></td></tr></table>";


print "</td><td>";


print "<table cellpadding=\"5px\"><tr><td><h4>";
print  $forecast[1]->day_of_week['data'];
print "<br><br>";
print "<img src=http://www.google.com" . $forecast[1]->icon['data'] . ">&nbsp;";
print "</h4></td><td><h4>";
print "<br><br>";
print  "&nbsp;" . $forecast[1]->condition['data'];
print "<br>";
print  "&nbsp;High&nbsp;" . $forecast[1]->high['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "<br>";
print  "&nbsp;Low&nbsp;" . $forecast[1]->low['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "</h4></td></tr></table>";

print "<table cellpadding=\"5px\"><tr><td><h4>";
print  $forecast[3]->day_of_week['data'];
print "<br><br>";
print "<img src=http://www.google.com" . $forecast[3]->icon['data'] . ">&nbsp;";
print "</h4></td><td><h4>";
print "<br><br>";
print  "&nbsp;" . $forecast[3]->condition['data'];
print "<br>";
print  "&nbsp;High&nbsp;" . $forecast[3]->high['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "<br>";
print  "&nbsp;Low&nbsp;" . $forecast[3]->low['data'] . "&nbsp;°F";
print "</h4></td></tr></table>";


print "</td></tr></table>";


print "</div></center>";


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in the url query parameter eo = utf-8. In this case, the answer will be exclusively the UTF-8 encoding. It helped me.

```
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=?????&degree=??????&oe=utf-8&hl=es
```