# Does sometime fputs() or fwrite() encode html special characters?

Tags: php, html, string, character-encoding, htmlspecialchars

I am outputting a string that consists of html content to a html file, but in the html file the html special characters are encoded (for example ***`"`*** in ***`\&quot;`*** ). I've even used htmlspecialcharacters_decode before using the write functions. The wierd part is that on my computer the characters are not encoded, while uploaded on some server are encoded. How can I deal with this problem?

Anticipated thanks!

Comment: Could you be seeing some UTF-8 or other encoding? There is a good discussion here on this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6337131/1132976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably suffering from [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)

Check you phpinfo();

To clear Magic Quotes look into the discussion at php.net:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Example (c) jeremysawesome:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, create_function('&$val', '$val = stripslashes($val);'));
```

Comment: yes, that's the problem ...too sad I don't have control over the online server.