# write utf-8 characters to file with fputcsv in php

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I want to try write Persian character in CSV file in PHP, I am using `fputcsv` function but how can write UTF-8 character to CSV file with `fputcsv`?

Part of my code:

```
$df = fopen($filepath, 'w');
fputcsv($df, array($coupon->code, $discount->label));
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Try this:

```
$df = fopen($filepath, 'w');
fprintf($df, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
fputcsv($df, array($coupon->code, $discount->label));
```

the line `fprintf($df, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));` writes file header for correct encoding.

Comment: You also have to take consideration in excel perspective. Make sure the excel already encoded in UTF-8

Comment: Could you please explain what the three characters are and what is their purpose in fixing the UTF8 problem?

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri those bytes make up the Byte Order mark (BOM) for UTF-8

Comment: This works great *but* in my case it makes some fields not to be printed to the excel file. Any idea why is that?

Comment: See also answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447325/php-export-csv-utf-8-with-bom-doesnt-work - if this doesn't work need to echo the characters before as well

Answer (score 36):

Try this also:

```
$df = fopen($filepath, 'w');
$array = array($coupon->code, $discount->label);
$array = array_map("utf8_decode", $array);
fputcsv($df, $array);
```

Comment: What does this answer do?

Comment: This will **decode** your UTF8 strings into single byte ISO-8859-1. This **NOT** what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @FarisRayhan Same things here.. :(

Comment: This is clearer in my opinion and leaves the work to be done by utf8_decode and not requiring the reader to obey the BOM.

Answer (score 8):

If you want make a UTF-8 file for excel, use this simple solution:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

//add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel 
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
```

See the original answer [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php#121950) on the official PHP page.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to others, but works for me

```
fputs($output_file, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) );
```

before `fputcsv` your data