# PHP fputcsv does not display Chinese Character Correctly

Tags: php, excel, character-encoding, chinese-locale, fputcsv

I need your help to finish my project. I take the data from my json files, some of which consist of chinese characters, but when I try to write to .csv it does not display properly.

This is my code

```
function writeCsv()
{                                                        
    $resource = fopen('c:/xampp/test.json','w');
    $csvBodyData = [ 'item'=> '逆始感録機政'];
    fputcsv($resource, $csvBodyData);   
}
```

I have tried the following solution but it's still not working.

[write utf-8 characters to file with fputcsv in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988581/write-utf-8-characters-to-file-with-fputcsv-in-php)

I got this character "???".

Comment: Have you tried solution with utf_decode from this answer?

Comment: yes already, using utf8_encode or utf8_decode only generate nonsense character @Ivan Kalita

Comment: I have just tried your code sample and it works on PHP7.0.22 and mac OS Sierra. What version of PHP are you using? What OS?

Comment: I use PHP 5.6.31 also macOs sierra. Is there any consideration from php depedency or excel setting itself ?

Comment: You see "???" character in Excel? Can you please try to just `cat test.json`?

Comment: Sorry the file inside fopen should be in csv file. So it should be fopen('c:/xampp/test.csv.','w'). Not json file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158041/discussion-between-ivan-kalita-and-faris-rayhan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the problem was not in PHP. When you open a csv file in Excel it shows you a window, where you can setup CSV importing options like delimiter and encoding. You should choose `UTF-8` encoding to view those Chinese characters.