# How to keep the Chinese or other foreign language as they are instead of converting them into codes?

Tags: php, domdocument, cjk, mb-convert-encoding

`DOMDocument` seems to convert Chinese characters into codes, for instance,

**你的乱发** will become `ä½ çš„ä¹±å‘`

How can I keep the Chinese or other foreign language as they are instead of converting them into codes?

Below is my simple test,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

If I add this below before loadHTML(),

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

I get,

```
&#20320;&#30340;&#20081;&#21457;
```

Even though the coverted codes will be displayed as Chinese characters, `&#20320;&#30340;&#20081;&#21457;` still are not `你的乱发` what I am after....

Comment: That's not "converting them into codes," that's "breaking the encoding." What is the encoding of the original data? Are you sure the file is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: The characters are displayed in ASCII instead of UTF-8. Do you have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 in the head section of  you html file?

Comment: yes I have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in the head section of my html file. But I found anyway to get around to this issue. thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Please add your solution / workaround as an answer below and accept it. Your question is still marked as not-solved albeit it has a solution. Please help us making this site better. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> DOMDocument seems to convert Chinese characters into codes [...]. How can I keep the Chinese or other foreign language as they are instead of converting them into codes?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

If you're using the [`loadHTML`](http://php.net/domdocument.loadhtml) function to load a HTML chunk. By default `DOMDocument` expects that string to be in HTML's default encoding (`ISO-8859-1`) however most often the charset (sic!) is meta-information provided next to the string you're using and not inside. To make this more complicated, that meta-information be be even inside the string.

Anyway as you have not shared the string data of the HTML and you have not specified the encoding, it's hard to tell specifically what is going on.

I assume the HTML is UTF-8 encoded but this is not signalled within the HTML string. So the following work-around can help:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);

// dirty fix
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item)
    if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE)
        $doc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper
```

It injects an encoding hint on the very beginning (and removes it after the HTML has been loaded). From that point on, `DOMDocument` will return UTF-8 (as always).

Comment: Also work with `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` which might be more HTML friendly. A more in deep discussion is within a [similar answer to question "PHP DomDocument failing to handle utf-8 characters (☆)"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11310258/367456).

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this thread when searching for a solution of a similar problem, i after loading the html properly and doing some parsing with Xpath etc... my text ends up like this:

```
&#20320;&#30340;&#20081;&#21457;
```

this display fine in the body of the HTML, but won't display properly in a style or script tag (e.g. setting chinese-fonts).

to fix this, do the reverse lauthiamkok did:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
```

if for any reason the first workaround doesn't work for you, try this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `ä½ çš„ä¹±å‘` is actually Windows Latin 1 (not ASCII, there are no diacritics in ASCII). Somewhere along the way your UTF-8 text got saved as Windows Latin 1....