# xml encoding error

Tags: php, xml, encoding, character-encoding

i have this code xml

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-7");?>
<pages>
<link>
<title>κεμενο</title>
<url>http://www.example.com</url>
</link>
</pages>
```

and the html code here for live search when i have latin characters on y xml it's working fine[image] but when i change the characters from english to greek i have this error message.
**Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE1 0x3C 0x2F 0x74 in /Applications/XAMPP/**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-7" />
<script>
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you change the `charset=ISO-8859-7` to `charset=utf-8` do you also convert the actual file's encoding to utf-8? Which editor do you use?

Answer (score 2):

> Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding

... so I guess your question is how to indicate encoding in XML. Since it appears to be a static document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-7"?>
<pages>
<link>
<title>κεμενο</title>
<url>http://www.example.com</url>
</link>
</pages>
```

Depending your PHP settings, you may need to obfuscate the `<?` tag so it doesn't get interpreted as a PHP tag.

Comment: but when i include encoding UTF-8 it doesn't appear the greek characters

Comment: So, why do you mention UTF-8 now? If you want to use **ISO-8859-7**, type `encoding="ISO-8859-7"` and save your file as **ISO-8859-7**. If you want to use `UTF-8`, type `encoding="UTF-8"` and save your file as **UTF-8**. As simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the method `DOMDocument::load()` to load an XML document from a file.

That file is making use of the `ISO-8859-7` encoding, however, the XML does not signal this encoding in it's XML Declaration (btw, the `header()` call does not signal the encoding for `load()`).

Therefore DOMDocument assumes the file is in UTF-8, however it runs over illegal binary sequences:

The binary octet `"\xE2"` signals two folloing octets encoding one Unicode code-point. However the next two octets in your case are `"\x3C\x2F"` which are no valid continuation bytes.

See again the error message:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE1 0x3C 0x2F 0x74 in ...

This hints two potential solutions:

1. Indicate the encoding.
2. Provide the XML string as UTF-8 encoding.

The first option would mean to add an XML Declaration on top of the file signalling the encoding used:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-7\"?>
<pages>
```

This file can then be loaded and re-encoded:

```
$doc->load($path);
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
```

The second alternative is to re-encode the string *before* you load it in, however you normally won't need to do that if you set the the XML declaration which I do recommend.

Re-encoding a string (not a filename!) works the following:

```
$xmlUTF_8 = iconv('ISO-8859-7', 'UTF-8', $xmlISO_8859_7);
```

Hope this helps. Also see as well [How to keep the Chinese or other foreign language as they are instead of converting them into codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237238/how-to-keep-the-chinese-or-other-foreign-language-as-they-are-instead-of-convert) and the other linked questions there that are showing the workarounds.