# PHP DomXPath encoding issue after xpath

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

If I use `echo $doc->saveHTML();` It will show the characters accordingly , but once it reaches the xml? at xpath to extract the element , the issues are back again.

I cant seem to display the characters properly. How do i convert it properly. I'm getting:

```
婢跺繐顒滈拺鍙ョ瀵偓鐞涱偊鈧繑妲戦挅鍕綍婢舵牕顨� 闂€鍌溾敄缂侊綀濮虫稉濠呫€� 娑擃叀顣荤純鎴犵綍閺冭泛鐨绘總鍏呯瑐鐞涳綀鏉藉▎
```

Instead of proper Chinese:

```
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta charset="gbk"/></head>
```

My PHP code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a2106.m874.1000384.41.aG3Kbi&id=20811635147&_u=o1ffj7oi9ad3&scm=1029.newlist-0.1.16&ppath=&sku=');
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// Based on Article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309194/php-domdocument-failing-to-handle-utf-8-characters/11310258#11310258
$searchPage = mb_convert_encoding($html,"HTML-ENTITIES","GBK");
$doc->loadHTML($searchPage);
// echo $doc->saveHTML(); 

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail']/div[1]/h3");

foreach ($elements as $e) {
   //echo $e->nodeValue;
   echo mb_convert_encoding($e->nodeValue,"utf-8","gbk");
}
```

Comment: `gbk` encoding is [not supported](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php). use `GB18030` or `EUC-CN` instead.

Comment: @HashemQolami but i manage to mv_convert to GBK without issues, it's only whewn it becomes a DOMpath($doc) things goes wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have the *to_encoding* and *from_encoding* parameters the wrong way around in your last call to [*mb_convert_encoding*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). The content returned from the XPath query is encoded as UTF-8, but you assumedly want the output encoded as gbk (given that you've set the meta charset to "gbk").

So the final loop should be:

```
foreach ($elements as $e) {
  echo mb_convert_encoding($e->nodeValue,"gbk","utf-8");
}
```

The *to_encoding* is "gbk", and the *from_encoding* is "utf-8".

That said, the answer given by **AgreeOrNot** should work too, if you are happy with the page being encoded as UTF-8.

---

As for how the encoding process works, internally *DOMDocument* uses UTF-8, so that is why the results you get by from your xpath queries are UTF-8, and why you need to convert that to gbk with *mb_convert_encoding* if that is the character set you need.

When you call *loadHTML*, it attempts to detect the source encoding, and then convert the input from that encoding to UTF-8. Unfortunately the detection algorithm doesn't always work very well.

For example, although your example page has set the *charset* metatag, that metatag is not recognised by *loadHTML*, so it defaults to assuming the source encoding is Latin1. It would have worked if you had used an *http-equiv* metatag specifying the *Content-Type*.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gbk" />
```

The alternative is to avoid the problem altogether, but by converting all non-ASCII characters to html entities (as you have done). That way it doesn't matter if *loadHTML* detects the character encoding correctly, because there won't be any characters that need converting.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already converted the document to html entities, you don't need to convert encoding when you print the result. So:

```
echo $e->nodeValue;
// echo mb_convert_encoding($e->nodeValue,"utf-8","gbk");
```

The reason you didn't get the correct output is that you put `<meta charset="gbk"/>` in your html while it should be `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`.