# Properly handling escaped unicode characters in php

Tags: php, unicode

Using php I parse a textfile that contains unicode characters like

Just reading-in the file without any further encoding/decoding the smiley is parsed, then json_encoded and the ouput is `\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u008d`

A javascript file gets the .json data and outputs the 4 escaped characters as `ð`

Looking at a unicode table the symbol is called "SMILING FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES" and has the unicode number `U+1F60D` (128525)

Is there a way to convert the 4 code units to the unicodenumber or ideally to a proper html-encoded way, in this case `&#x1F60D;`

looking at conversions, the utf 8 code units look similar (F0 9F 98 8D 0A 0A), but I can't reproduce the 4 escaped units I get, so I don't even know what I'm looking at

Update: I made a mistake and edited the second paragraph: `\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u008d` already is the result of json_encode();

Here is the basic function to read the data from the file, looking at the source the smiley is "hardcoded", so you actually see it

```
function readLocalFile() {
  $file_html = fopen('output.html', "r");
  $html = "";

  while(!feof($file_html)) {
    $html .= fgets($file_html);
  }

  fclose($file_html);

  // here I use regex to filter for specific tags, the result is an array
  $cleanData = parseData($html);

  saveToFile(json_encode($cleanData)); 
}
```

I just created a dummy.html with just  as the content and this returns the correct result `\ud83d\ude0d`, in the context of the whole data it still is mangled as described above, weird

I have to look at the way the data is saved to `output.html`, that's where the problem has to be. I've been looking at the wrong part of the problem the whole time, d'oh!

Last Update: finally found the error. It was in the parseData-function, loadHTML somehow garbled the content, found the solution here:
[PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)

Comment: This _IS_ UTF-8, the 0A 0A at the end are the next characters (CR or LF) already.

Comment: Your input string is broken, `\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u008d` is obviously *not* `U+1F60D` because that would be `\ud83d\ude0d`. You should take a look why you have that in the input string. This looks a bit like a misunderstood "conversion" from UTF-8 into something JSON, probably due to broken PHP json unicode handling ([#62010](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62010)?) You should share some code to say more.

Comment: Just seeing your edit. Can you provide a sample of [the string hex-encoded](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1057572/367456) before you pass it into `json_encode`? If it's very long or contains private information, maybe just reduce it to the part that makes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

What puzzles me with your question is the `\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u008d` sequence. It just does not sound like anything standardized.

As you wrote this is about 
[Unicode Character 'SMILING FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES' (U+1F60D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f60d/index.htm). The `\u` based notation you offer seem to suggest this would be Javascript / JSON encoded unicode characters. So let's review this a little:

- JSON uses UTF-16 surrogate pairs for anything not in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF).
- U+1F60D is *not* in the basic multilinguage pane.
- It's UTF-16 encoding therefore is 0xD83D 0xDE0D
- This is not what you have
- It's UTF-8 encoding is xF0 0x9F 0x98 0x8D
- This looks like what you've misused.

After this quick analysis, the answer is the following: If you can consider all `\u????` sequences to be equally misused to encode UTF-8 binary sequences then all you need to do is to hook onto each of those, combine the characters that are encoded in the last hex-number which is the pair of two hexdigits at the end (position 5+6 / index 4+5) and put it together.

As this seems broken I do not suggest full-source-code here as I don't want to especially support that practice - you need to fix that in the encoding - however you can find code outlined in an answer to [*PHP DomDocument failing to handle utf-8 characters (☆)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11310258/367456).

So fix the input string containing wrong `\u` (u stands here for unicode, but it's not in your case as those imply UTF-16 *not* binary octets). You need to understand where those wrong `\u` sequences are introduced, it's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is UTF-8 data decoded as ISO-8859-1 (latin1) to Unicode, then JSON encoded.  If you:

1. Decode the JSON to Unicode.
2. Encode to bytes with latin-1.
3. Decode to Unicode with UTF-8.

This should give you the the correct character.  I don't do PHP, but here's a Python proof:

```
>>> '\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u008d'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'\U0001f60d'
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name('\U0001f60d')
'SMILING FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES'
```

How the data got garbled in the first place could be the HTML was actually UTF-8-encoded, but incorrectly declared ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I used loadHTML() and it handled the html-document I provided as ISO-8859-1 by default, so I had to declare it an UTF-8 document! As I learned, "there's an issue with DOMDocument and loadHTML garbling UTF-8 content". This answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/2748220