# Font or Unicode issue on Scraping

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

Am trying to scrape info from a site.

The site have like this

```
127 East Zhongshan No 2 Rd; 中山东二路127号
```

But when i try to scrap it & echo it then it will show

```
127 East Zhongshan No 2 Rd; ä¸­å±±ä¸äºè·¯127å·
```

I also try UTF-8

There is my php code

now please help me for solve this problem.

```
function GrabPage($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}
$GrabData   = GrabPage($site);

$dom    = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($GrabData);

$xpath  = new DOMXpath($dom);


$mainElements = array();
$mainElements = $xpath->query("//div[@class='col--one-whole mv--col--one-half wv--col--one-whole'][1]/dl/dt");

foreach ($mainElements as $Names2) {
    $Name2  = $Names2->nodeValue;
    echo "$Name2";
}
```

Comment: This is site URL: http://www.lonelyplanet.com/china/shanghai/transport/transportation-travel-services/jinling-road-ferry

Comment: loadHTML expectes Latin-1 encoded data, see [PHP DomDocument failing to handle utf-8 characters (☆)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11309194/367456) for details.

Comment: What you've got here is a HTML 5+ document with the `<meta charset='utf-8'>` tag. It seems that this tag is not lying about the file encoding so it is *UTF-8*. Default encoding in HTML 0-4.x is *ISO-8895-1*. **DOMDocument** in PHP expects HTML 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to set the charset before anything else on top of PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

You need to convert the html markup you got with `mb_convert_encoding`:

```
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($GrabData, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Du3gfM)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to see if the captured HTML source is properly encoded. If yes try

```
utf8_decode($Name2)
```

This should get your string ready for saving as well as printing

Comment: You are also right. Thanks.

Comment: This method will result in data-loss. The answer given is no good suggestion.

Comment: @FerozAhmed Gald that it helped..!!

Comment: @hakre can you please elaborate how a dat loss can occur using this method?

Comment: UTF-8 has far more characters that the result of utf8_decode can express. For all those characters not-expressible, loss will occur.

Comment: @hakre Thank you, this info was new to me, I learned something new