# Prevent external html to interfere entire page template

Tags: javascript, html

My mission is to explore blogs and get their latest post. Now I have script that do the task and store the content as `html` in database.
Everything works properly except template inference. Means that if the content html code for example has an extra `</div>` or forget to close a tag, it will ruin my entire page.

**Question:** Is there any way to limit the external content to one division and therefore if external code had some problems, just influence template of that `div` box not entire template?

[Link to correct template](http://yushia.blogma.net/541064/%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A2%D9%87%D9%86%DA%AF-%D8%AC%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D8%B5%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%88-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%B6%DB%8C-%D8%B2%D8%B1%D9%84%DA%A9%DB%8C-%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%82%D8%B5%D9%87-%D9%BE%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AE%D9%88%D9%86)
[Link to damaged template](http://nasimroooz.blogma.net/544753/%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%B4)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What programming language are you using to get this content?

Comment: PHP, and if it's matter, tell me to add it to my question please, thanks

Comment: consume RSS instead or parse and serialize the html before re-serving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify that by using a library that fix the malformed code that was scrapped.

You can do like that:

```
<?php
$content = '<div><p>I am a bad guy, and i am gonna put an additional div at the end.</p></div></div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
libxml_clear_errors();
$content = trim($dom->saveHTML());


echo $content;
```

It will return:

```
<div><p>I am a bad guy, and i am gonna put an additional div at the end.</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks lago it works correctly but it cant support utf8 encoding and the result are like this: `…Ø®Ø§Ù„ÙØ§Ù† Ø­Ù…Ù„Ù‡ Ø±ÙˆØ³ÛŒÙ‡ Ø¨Ù‡ Ø¯Ø§Ø¹Ø´ `

Comment: Yes, i recommend you see that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309194/php-domdocument-failing-to-handle-utf-8-characters just to do not duplicate here.

Answer (score 1):

The only safe way to ensure it doesn't affect anything else on your page, as far as I'm aware, is to iframe it. Anything else is going to be injecting into your page, so you'd be risking things you've mentioned like unclosed tags, style tags that override your CSS, potentially malicious JS etc unless you do some serious parsing and error correction. Some of this is done by things like JQuery's AJAX function, but if you can't risk anything at all, I'd go with an iframe that displays a page that renders your scraped content.