# Why is DOMDocument converting both html quote-entities to actual quotes?

Tags: php, domdocument

I've been at this for half a day, so now it's time to ask for help.

What I'd like is for DOMDocument to leave existing entities and utf-8 characters alone. I'm now thinking this is not possible using only DOMDocument.

```
$html =
'<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>&#39; &quot; & &lt; © 庭</p>
    </body>
</html>';
```

Then I run:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOERROR);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

And get entity output:

```
input: &#39; &quot; & &lt; © 庭
output: ' " &amp; &lt; &copy; &#24237;
```

Why is DOMDocument converting `&#39;` and `&quot;` to actual quote marks? The only thing it didn't touch was `&lt;`.

Pretty sure the copyright symbol is being converted because DOMDocument doesn't think the input html is utf-8, but I'm utterly confused why it's converting the quotes back to non-entities.

I thought the `mb_convert_encoding` [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/142233) would fix the utf-8 issue, but it hasn't.

Neither has the `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$html);` [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/142233).

Comment: `DOMDocument` parses everything into a canonical internal form of the DOM. It doesn't remember the format you used in the input HTML. So there's no way to get it to leave things alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested about a dozen HTML parsers written in PHP and the only one that worked as expected was [HTML5DOMDocument](https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php/) recommended in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/142233).

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dom = new IvoPetkov\HTML5DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOERROR);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result:

```
input: &#39; &quot; &lt; © 庭 &nbsp; &
output: &#39; &quot; &lt; © 庭 &nbsp; &amp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a specific element to the `saveHTML()` method. This will have it do a minimalist approach to encoding entities. It will still encode those that are necessary. I don't think there's a way to prevent all entity encoding from happening, but it won't try to encode every entity it can.

```php
$html = $dom->saveHTML($dom);
// ' " &amp; &lt; © 庭
```

Comment: This helps, thanks. I'll see what I can come up with. [Here's a nice little loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931835/142233) I'll modify and try.