# Parser RSS e DOMDocument::load

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a small problem with a script that reads an XML file and prints the output:

```
<?php

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load("http://www.tripadvisor.it/Feeds-d235955-treviews.xml");
  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
      echo $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
      echo $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
      echo $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
      echo $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  }

?>
```

If you use this script on my personal domain (hosting) it works fine, but if I use on my VPS does not work and returns these errors:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://www.tripadvisor.it/Feeds-d235955-treviews.xml) [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/AAA/public_html/test.php on line 4
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.tripadvisor.it/Feeds-d235955-treviews.xml" in /home/AAA/public_html/test.php on line 4
```

Which PHP or APACHE settings that may cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As file_get_contents is not working in your server so try to use use curl to connect with tripadvisor server as below

```
<?php
$init = curl_init();
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.tripadvisor.it/Feeds-d235955-treviews.xml');
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec ($init);
curl_close ($init);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($contents);
print"<pre>";
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: I have this error if I use this script :"Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.tripadvisor.it/Feeds-d235955-treviews.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/AAA/public_html/test.php on line 2"

Comment: As file_get_contents is not working in you server so try curl. I have updated my last answer please check

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Space required after the Public Identifier in /home/AAA/public_html/test.php on line 7

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> in /home/AAA/public_html/test.php on line 7

Comment: Check this problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899274/php-simplexml-why-does-simplexml-load-string-fail-to-parse-google-weather-a

Comment: I think the problem is in settings VPS, no script works, because they can not read the file. <! DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "- / / IETF / / DTD HTML 2.0 / / EN"> is the header page 404. Which php or apache setting that may cause problems?

Answer (score 1):

Try regular expression to get xml tags in php .
Get xml with php curl then use regular expression.
Try under following link
http://www.bobulous.org.uk/coding/php-xml-regex.html

Comment: combine Chauhan's answer and function from that link

Comment: He's doing things just fine. Regular expressions are an awful tool to handle XML.