# In php how to display chinese character?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, cjk

what I build now is I grabbing from RSS feed in chinese RSS website, but once I echo out is blank, my code was work on english RSS, I try a lot of decode,iconv, header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");, but still the same cannot display any chinese word on my screen.

here is my coding:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
function getrssfeed($feed_url){    
$Current = date("Y-m-d" ,strtotime("now"));
$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);    
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$body = "";
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $entry){     
        $body .= get_html_translation_table(htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags($Current ." ". $entry->description))) . "\n\n";      
        //$result = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $body);
        $i++;       
        if($i==5) {
            break;      
        }       
    }
echo $body;
}
```

getrssFeed("http://news.baidu.com/n?cmd=1&class=enternews&tn=rss");

Can you guy help me how to solve my problem ?

thank you

Comment: Dont you even get like ?????????? questions marks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899274/php-simplexml-why-does-simplexml-load-string-fail-to-parse-google-weather-a

Comment: a blank php page usually means an error with display errors off

Answer (score 1):

in your HTML header put this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>
```

Comment: I tested, still the same thing happen, displaying white blank page, If I change the rss link to english, it's work

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to do

1. Set document type or header as

> content="text/html;charset=utf-8"

1. Save those user Chinese characters in database with field collation as utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use this function with

> mb_convert_encoding

,but at the same time ,you should attention the native document charset must be utf-8 or gb2312