# Printing string with special characters

Tags: php, unicode, special-characters

I want to echo a string `京icp备09001224号` (some characters are in Chinese Language) .
But when i do echo for such string, it prints `äº¬icpå¤‡09001224å`·

How can i get the exact sting as output?

thanks.

Comment: Too little detail about what misinterprets the encoding. Go through the basics here: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: utf-8 encoded is enabled. Even i don't know what misinterprets.

Comment: could't find any function like magically_fix_this()

Comment: Don't forget to save your code file in UTF-8 and send proper `content-type=text/html; charset: utf-8` headers + proper `<meta>` tags in the HTML.

Comment: LOL. You two may just have created a new meme.

Answer (score 1):

similar question asked here [In php how to display chinese character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479668/in-php-how-to-display-chinese-character)

And here is your solution, you need to specify the encoding, to display the characters.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>
<?php echo "京icp备09001224号"; ?>
```

will output like

```
京icp备09001224号
```

and test your php file encoding if this does not work. Encode your php file with utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

`äº¬icpå¤‡09001224å` is your text printed out in Windows-Latin-1. One of the elements in your toolchain is not set to use UTF-8.